# how to make read only file/directory in Mac writable

Tags: node.js, macos, macos-sonoma, simple-git

I have a project which uses Simple-git to clone the repo in my local folder
but due to read-only file system in Mac it is not able to make a new directory

Would Like to know if there's a way to grant +rw access to a particular directory...

tried `chmod +rw src` but it ain't working

code I ran : `await simpleGit().clone(url,"/deploy/"+id);`
Error: `GitError: fatal: could not create leading directories of '/deploy/Izste': Read-only file system`

Comment: There are important details missing from your question. ***How/where*** did you try `chmod +rw src`? How is `src` related to `/deploy`? Why are you cloning into your root directory? That is ill-advised.